# Chakra UI, Tabs onChange method throws Maximum update depth exceeded on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs, setstate, chakra-ui

I have the following code,
React throws Maximum update depth exceeded error, whenever I change the change the
index, It is somehow forming an infinite loop,
and the onChange method is being called on render, how can I fix it?

```
const ChecklistNavbarTabs = () => {
    const [tabIndex, setTabIndex] = useState(0);

    return (
        <Tabs
            variant='unstyled'
            alignItems='center'
            width='full'
            bgColor='header.100'
            height='full'
            onChange={(index:number)=>{setTabIndex(index)}}
        >
            <TabList color='blackAlpha.600' justifyContent='space-between' m='3'>
                <Flex
                    alignContent='space-between'
                    borderRadius='4'
                    justifyContent='space-between'
                    border='1px solid'
                    borderColor='blackAlpha.500'
                >
                    <Flex justifyContent='space-between'>
                        <Flex>
                            <Tab
                                bgColor='gray.100'
                                borderColor='blackAlpha.500'
                                border='1px solid'
                            >
                                <Text>Header Fields</Text>
                            </Tab>
                        </Flex>
                        <Flex>
                            <Tab
                                bgColor='gray.100'
                                borderColor='blackAlpha.500'
                                border='1px solid'
                            >
                                <Text>Checkpoint</Text>
                            </Tab>
                        </Flex>
                        <Flex>
                            <Tab
                                bgColor='gray.100'
                                borderColor='blackAlpha.500'
                                border='1px solid'
                            >
                                <Text>Checklist Item</Text>
                            </Tab>
                        </Flex>
                        <Flex>
                            <Tab
                                bgColor='gray.100'
                                borderColor='blackAlpha.500'
                                border='1px solid'
                            >
                                <Text>Footer Field</Text>
                            </Tab>
                        </Flex>
                    </Flex>
                </Flex>
                <Flex justifyContent='flex-end' flex='1'>
                    <AddHeaderFieldButton />
                </Flex>
            </TabList>
            <Flex>
                <TabPanels>
                    <TabPanel>
                        <ChecklistHeaderFieldTable table={navbarData} />
                    </TabPanel>
                    <TabPanel>
                        <CreateCheckpointTable table={CreateCheckPointData} />
                    </TabPanel>
                    <TabPanel>
                        {/* <CreateChecklistItemTable table={AddChecklistItemData} /> */}
                    </TabPanel>
                    <TabPanel>
                        {/* <ChecklistFooterTable table={AddFooterTableData} /> */}
                    </TabPanel>
                </TabPanels>
            </Flex>
        </Tabs>
    );
};

export default ChecklistNavbarTabs;
```

I have tried, useMemo and useCallback as well, to memoize the results and stop re-render though I don't know if that the right way.

Please help me solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/disclosure/tabs#usage) says the following:

> You can render any element within Tabs, but TabList should only have Tab as children, and TabPanels should have TabPanel as children.
>
> Tabs expects TabList and TabPanels as children. The order doesn't matter, you can have TabList at the top, at the bottom, or both.

I believe nesting `Tab` inside of multiple `Flex` components is the cause of the onChange infinite loop issue. `Tab` should be a direct child of `TabList`. You'd likely also need to remove `<AddHeaderFieldButton />` or place it inside of a `Tab` component. Also `TabPanels` should not be wrapped in a `Flex` component.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem was that the tab panels had react-table tables as children, and there was an issue that I did not use useMemo while declaring table headers.

simply then fixed it via useMemo